# Contact Application in Android

Tags: android, kotlin, android-cursoradapter

I want to build a contact app which reads the contacts from the android device and show it in a list view. On clicking an item of list view a new activity will be opened where the details of the contact will be displayed. I have displayed the list view and am facing problems in getting the data from the simplecursoradapter. Can someone help me with the setOnItemClickListener() method?

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        read()
    }
    fun read()
    {
        var cursor : Cursor? = 
  contentResolver.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
            null,null,null,null)

        startManagingCursor(cursor)
        var selected_columns = arrayOf(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME,ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER,
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone._ID)
        var to =  intArrayOf(android.R.id.text1)
        var simple : SimpleCursorAdapter = SimpleCursorAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,cursor,selected_columns,to,0)
        my_listview.adapter = simple

        my_listview.setOnItemClickListener { parent, view, position, id ->

            val intent = Intent(this, Contactdetails::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
        }

    }


   }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to get data from `SimpleCursorAdapter`. Just do it like so:

```
my_listview.setOnItemClickListener { parent, view, position, id ->

    val intent = Intent(this, Contactdetails::class.java)
    intent.putExtra("CONTACT_DATA" , cursor.getString(position))
    startActivity(intent)

}
```

Comment: what does cursor.getString(position) return? Actually I want the contact name and contact number to be send to another activity? Can you please help me how can I get these two fields?